# Upstream is a repo or a branch?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a question around upstream, if I follow a right process to keep my fork updated with the original repo. I should do something like

```
git remote add upstream 'link'
```

and then

```
git fetch upstream
```

to update that upstream/master

that means, it is a tracking repo. Can it be created as upstream tracking branch also? and then I can switch like

```
git checkout branchname
```

What's the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: Here `upstream` is a repo. But I'm unsure I got what *is* the question.

Comment: If its a repo, when did I switch to this repo during the git fetch command?

Comment: "switch to this repo"? In what sense? You can have several (or none) distant repos configured, and when you `fetch` you can specify or not from which you want to fetch (or from all). Then again, look in [fetch man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_description) : "When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing *remote repositories* with *remote tracking branches*.

#### What's a remote repository?

Given a repository `R`, a *remote repository* is a clone of `R` that's physically separated from it, usually by a network.

If you want to keep track of what happens in a remote repository, you add a reference to it from `R`. This reference is called a *remote* and it's usually named `origin`, by convention.

From the Git glossary:

> Most projects have at least one upstream project which they track. By default origin is used for that purpose.

#### What does "upstream" mean?

As far as Git is concerned, all repository are created equal — *however*, in almost all projects there is a hierarchy of repositories, where at the top is the repository everybody agrees on is the *canonical* one.

Here's an example:

```
      +-------+
      |       |
      |  Git  |         <-- upstream
      |       |
      +---+---+
          ^
          |
+---------+---------+
|                   |
|  Git for Windows  |   <-- origin
|                   |
+---------+---------+
          ^
          |
   +------+------+
   |             |
   |  Your Fork  |
   |             |
   +-------------+
```

Seen from the perspective of `Your Fork`, if you want to track what happens in `Git for Windows`, your would call that remote repository `origin` because that's the one you cloned.

If you also want to keep track of what happens in the canonical `Git` repository, you would name that remote reference `upstream` because it's *further up* the hierarchy of repositories where changes *stream downwards*.

The [Git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) summarizes the [distinction between *origin* and *upstream* well](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeforiginaorigin):

> Most projects have at least one upstream project which they track. By default origin is used for that purpose. New upstream updates will be fetched into remote-tracking branches named origin/name-of-upstream-branch.

This brings us to our next question.

#### What's a remote tracking branch?

A *remote tracking branch* is a branch that exists in a remote repository that you want to track.

Again, from the [Git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_remote_tracking_branch):

> A ref that is used to follow changes from another repository.

These branches are usually named:

```
<remote-name>/<branch-name>
```

to allow you to differentiate them from your *local branches*, that is branches that exist only in your local repository.

For example:

```
upstream/master  <-- master branch in the upstream repo
origin/master    <-- master branch in the origin repo
master           <-- local master branch
```

Keep in mind that remote tracking branches are *read-only* — you can update them with whatever new commits happened in the remote branch by running `git fetch`, but you can't commit to them. In that sense, you can think of them more as *bookmarks*.

#### What's an upstream branch?

When you track a remote repository from a local one, chances are you'll be working on the same branches as your fellow contributors.

However, we know that *remote tracking branches* are just bookmarks, so we can't commit to them directly.

The solution is to create local branches (which we *can* commit to) and *associate* them to the remote branches. This allows us to quickly bring in changes from the *remote tracking branch* into our local one and vice versa using `git pull` and `git push`.

In this case, the Git glossary is a bit more mysterious with [its definition](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefupstreambranchaupstreambranch):

> **upstream branch**
>   The default branch that is merged into the branch in question.

In other words, an upstream branch is the *remote counterpart* of a local branch; this relationship exists solely as a convenient way of keeping those branches in sync without having to explicitly reference them by name.

Answer (score 0):

To update a fork, master branch:

```
git remote add upstream 'link'
git checkout master
git fetch upstream 
git merge upstream/master
git push origin
```